# How to get input integer value into char type variable using cin?

Tags: c++, types, char, int, cin

```
void defineEdge()
{
    char vertex1, vertex2;
    int charToInt = 0;

    while (charToInt != -1)
    {
        cout << "Define an edge by listing a pair of vertices (-1 to stop):  ";
        cin >> vertex1 >> vertex2;
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        charToInt = vertex1 - '0';

        // getVertexIndex() eventaully returns the index representing
        // [index of vertex1][index of vertex2] in 1-D array 
        // Assign 1 to represent the directed connection between 2 vertices 
        graphMatrix[getVertexIndex(vertex1, vertex2)] = 1;
    }

}
```

This is a member function part of my matrix representing graph class.
The matrix is adjacency matrix for unweighted directed graph.
The matrix is dynamically allocated as 1-D array and using row major order to access desired indices.

I am trying to get vertices like below to define the edge:

```
Define an edge by listing a pair of vertices (-1 to stop): A B
Define an edge by listing a pair of vertices (-1 to stop): B A
Define an edge by listing a pair of vertices (-1 to stop): -1 A
```

However, I get Debug Error whenever I input -1

> Run-Time Check Failure #3-The variable 'vertex2Index' is being used without being initialized.

I'm wondering if there's proper way to get integer value (i.g. -1) to 
char variable (i.g. vertex1)

EDIT: There's another integer list for storing vertex, so I want to get vertex1 and vertex2 to get the index of corresponding index using getVertexIndex().

Comment: Hmmmm. Doesn't "-1" is already 2 characters ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You can't read `A` into a `int`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I hadn't noticed the sample input.

Comment: Use `cin.peek()` to see if the next character in the stream is `'-'`, if so, read an `int`, otherwise read a `char`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you I think that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cin.peek()` as suggested in the comment.
Nevertheless, I feel it will be simpler to read into string, and use `stoi()`.
BTW, are you intentionally not skipping the last entry (with -1 as vertex1)?? this is unclear from your implementation.

Comment: thanks for answering:). so I should make a vertex list as a string list and read the line of string and break into tokens and store them into the vertex list?

Comment: @anthony_park That really depends on how you have you input file. if it is one large line with all pairs - yes, you will have to read all of them and break them into tokens. If, however, you have one vertex a line - you can read them one by one.

Comment: I solved the problem with reading the 2 vertices in a line of string as how sample output is showing. I appreciate your insight

Comment: I think that reading 2 vertices at a time also has the benefit of making the input file most human readable.